# Memory leak: blocks are still reachable - How to solve it?

Tags: c, error-handling, malloc, valgrind, fixed

I have found some similar topics here:
[Valgrind - blocks still reachable due to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16111854/17027132)
or here:
[Still Reachable Leak detected by Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3840582/17027132)
but none provided a solution. Hence, I want to raise this question again.

This is the result from valgrind:

```
==403== HEAP SUMMARY:
==403==     in use at exit: 7,791,056 bytes in 139,126 blocks
==403==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 3,970 frees, 8,023,256 bytes allocated
==403== 
==403== 7,791,056 bytes in 139,126 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==403==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==403==    by 0x401BBE: load (dictionary.c:121)
```

and this is the code where I allocate memory to a new node:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// ADDITIONAL functions
bool free_list(node *w);
unsigned int numeric(char c);

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26 * 28 * 28;
// Initialize number of word count in dictionary
int word_count = 0;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: initiate a node before looping
    node *n = table[hash(word)];
    // Checks if malloc succeeded, returns false if not
    while (true)
    {
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (strcasecmp(n->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            n = n->next;
        }
    }
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int ret;
    ret = tolower(word[0]) - 97 + 26 * numeric(word[1]);
    if (word[1] != '\0')
    {
        ret += 26 * 28 * numeric(word[2]);
    }
    return ret;
}

// ADDITION: Numeric char value
unsigned int numeric(char c)
{
    int ret;
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        ret = (tolower(c) - 96);
    }
    else if (c == '\0')
    {
        ret = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = 27;
    }
    return ret;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO: Open file
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open dictionary.\n");
        return false;
    }

    //Initialize the list to be NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    // COPY words in dictionary to hash table
    char c;
    char tmp[LENGTH + 1];
    int index = 0;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
    {
        if (c != '\n')
        {
            tmp[index] = c;
            index += 1;
        }
        else // means this is a full word
        {
            // Terminate current word
            tmp[index] = '\0';

            // Put the word to the hash
            // allocate memory to a new node
            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            // Checks if malloc succeeded, returns false if not
            if (n == NULL)
            {
                unload();
                return false;
            }
            // assign values to new node
            n->next = table[hash(tmp)];
            strcpy(n->word, tmp);

            // make the hash point to the new node
            table[hash(tmp)] = n;

            // Clear the tmp array for next word
            for (int i = 0; i < index + 1; i += 1)
            {
                tmp[index] = 0;
            }
            word_count += 1; //Increase word count for size function
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return word_count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        free_list(table[i]);
    }

    return true;
}

// Create free linked-list function
bool free_list(node *w)
{
    if (w == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (w->next == NULL)
    {
        free(w);

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        free_list(w->next);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The the line 121 in which HEAP SUMMARY reported a problem is the malloc line for a new node, in load() function: `node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));`

Could you please tell me why it leads to a memory leakage and how I can fix the problem?

Comment: `free()` the memory?

Comment: @KamilCuk the free() function works okay and had no issue in the valgrind report. However, valgrind still insists that my malloc has 1 memory leakage of 56 Bytes

Comment: You have to post an [MCVE], What is `node`? What is `unload()`? Where is `load` function? What is `table`? What is `hash`? Did you `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: @KamilCuk this is the Github link in case you need to see the whole code: https://github.com/me50/sonpnt/blob/cs50/problems/2021/x/speller/dictionary.c

Comment: Your repo is private, I get 404-not found. Please do not post messages to external services. Please make your question self-contained, with all possible data needed to reproduce the problem. Please include a minimal compilable version of the source code that reproduces the problem, including input, including `main`, including all `#include` into the question as text. See [ask].

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you, I have edited the post to include all the related functions. The only place in which Valgrind reported a problem is the malloc line for a new node, in `load()` function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your free function only free memory of last element :

```
bool free_list(node *w)
{
    if (w == NULL) // empty : no free
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (w->next == NULL) // free last element 
    {
        free(w);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        free_list(w->next); // try to free next element but not current
        return true;
    }
}
```

Should be modified as :

```
bool free_list(node *w)
{
    if (w == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // free next elements
    if (w->next != NULL)
    {
        free_list(w->next);
    }
    // free current
    free(w);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: OMG thank you so muchhhh! This saves my life. You understood my idea so well. But I still don't get why this change makes the difference. Would you mind explaining it a bit more to me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because of the (if else if else), your code could not read the point where it can free the current w except if it was the last : if w->next is not null you execute the code in the last else ie you free the w->next which seems to looks fine. But w is not freed after, so is w is not the last (w->next not NULL) is is not freed = memory leak.

Comment: thank you! now I have fully got it

Answer (score 0):

One problem is in your `free_list` function.

This recursive function will only free that last node in the list. This could be rewritten to not be recursive, but what you likely want in the last "else" code block is

```
free_list(w->next);
free(w);
return true;
```

Incidentally, why does this function have a return value? It always returns true, and you never check the return value when the function is called.